Keil µVision 5 extension for VS Code
I currently am on a Keil µVision project and i want to use the VS Code extension (more practical).
I work on a old project (on a STM32F05VG with Arm Compiler V5) but this extension supports Arm Compiler 6 only : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Arm.keil-studio-pack&ssr=false#overview
For now, i can't merge my project on Arm Compiler 6 version.
I want to be able to build, flash and use most of features used in Keil µVision.
And currently, no other extension works.
What can i try to do ?

Have you tried it and know it not to work?  I see nowhere where it says it only works with ARM Compiler v6.  It says it is for MDK v6, but that is confusing marketing.  MDK v6 refers to a suite of components of which MDK-ARM v5.xx is one and that includes both ARMCC v5 and ARM Compiler v6.

I dispute the "more practical" claim.  Clearly not if it is not working!  The plugin is relatively new.  Keil previously attempted a plug-in for Eclipse in an attempt to migrate from the somewhat old fashioned uVision IDE.  It was buggy and poorly supported and eventually abandoned.  A preference for VSCode is a personal opinion, rather than in any way "more practical".  For existing code maintenance, "practical" in the sense of getting work done would be to stick with the more mature tool.

I guess, as You're doing Embedded C programming on VS Code (~from tags you added). Most chances, if you're doing Assembly Language Programming. To compile ASM Lang.
Still, I'm not even a experienced guy, to help but just few days back I tried using Keil µVision. I was having some issues, so better I switched on VS Code. To code & compile in ASM, you can try using this extension :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xsro.masm-tasm
Drop any questions, if possible I'll try to help!
You can even reachout to their's community support : https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/keil-forum

Not an answer to the question.  Keil uVision is just the IDE component of Kiel ARM-MDK which includes a complete toolchain.  Moreover the OP has an existing project that he needs to build.  So the question is about opening and building an existing project using the existing toolchain.  In any event the plugin you posted supports building 16bit x86 assembler using antique "abandonware" tools in DOSBox.  Not at all about embedded development for the OPs target which is an ARM Cortex-M microcontroller. The link to the community support is worthy of a comment only.
